# Using a SASS variable as a value for CSS `content` property

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass

Hi!

This might be caused by my lack of understanding of SASS/Compass.

I'm trying to output grid width with the following SASS code:

```sass
$total-columns        : 4
$column-width         : 4em                 // each column is 4em wide
$gutter-width         : $column-width / 2   // 1em gutters between columns
$grid-padding         : $gutter-width / 2   // grid-padding equal to gutters

#page
  +container
  +susy-grid-background

  #block-block-3
    div.content
      p:first-of-type:after
        content: columns-width()
```

Nothing is printed into block 3. :(

I also tried `content: columns-width($total-columns)`, still nothing. If i do `content: "foo"`, "foo" does get printed.

What am i doing wrong? How do i see susy-calculated grid width? Also, can it be printed in `compass watch` output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, the solution is using [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```sass
content: "#{columns-width($total-columns)}"
```